Solana address length
I thought Solana address length is fixed.
My friend just managed to send funds to an address that was missing one letter at the end. And I can see both addresses on solscan. Does it mean they both are operational?

What you are seeing and used to is the base58 encoded version of your Solana address/public key.
In reality, the Solana address is indeed fixed -- It is 32 bytes long.
However, when converting from bytes to base58 (which is a more readable form), there can be a difference of length and the result could be 43 characters long, which is totally fine, although generally it is 44 characters long.

Solana public keys are comprised of 32 bytes of data. When you work with string public keys, which you are referring to, these are the 32 bytes of data encoded in base58, this means the resulting string can be between 32 and 44 characters.
https://solana.com/docs/more/exchange#validating-user-supplied-account-addresses-for-withdrawals
